# Two-way matrix optimization

Tags: optimization

I have run into a problem like this. Looks a bit unusual, but I think should be doable. Find $U$ achieving

$$\min_U  \left(  \| A - UW \|_2^2 + \| RU - H \|_2^2  \right)$$

$A,U,W,R,H$ are all matrices of dimension so that the operations above make sense. All the other matrices are given, except $U$. The norm is the Frobenius norm.

The difficulty here is that $U$ is multiplied from different sides in different terms.

Any ideas?

Comment: $U\mapsto A-UW$ and $U\mapsto RU-H$ are both linear operators on matrices, and the Frobenius norm is just the $L^2$ norm on the entries of the matrix. So you just have a quadratic minimization problem on your hands.

Comment: Yes, it's quadratic, but how do you express the answer in terms of $A, W, R, H$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's compute the gradient of $g(U) = \|A - U W \|^2$.
We'll use the fact that if $P,Q \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, then
$\langle P, Q \rangle = \text{Tr}(P Q^T)$.
\begin{align}
g(U + \Delta U) &= \|A - U W - \Delta U W \|^2 \\
&\approx \|A - U W \|^2 - 2 \langle A - U W, \Delta U W \rangle \\
&= g(U) - 2 \text{Tr}\left((A - UW) W^T \Delta U^T \right) \\
&= g(U) - 2 \langle (A - UW)W^T, \Delta U \rangle.
\end{align}
Comparing this with $g(U + \Delta U) \approx g(U) + \langle \nabla g(U), \Delta U \rangle$,
we see that
\begin{equation}
\nabla g(U) = -2(A - UW) W^T.
\end{equation}

Next let's compute the gradient of $h(U) = \|RU - H \|^2$.
We'll use the fact that if $P, Q \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$,
then $\langle P, Q \rangle = \text{Tr}(P^T Q)$.
\begin{align}
h(U + \Delta U) &= \| RU - H + R \Delta U \|^2 \\
&\approx \| RU - H \|^2 + 2 \langle RU - H, R \Delta U \rangle \\
&= h(U) + 2 \text{Tr} \left((RU - H)^T R \Delta U \right) \\
&= h(U) + 2 \langle R^T (RU - H), \Delta U \rangle.
\end{align}
Comparing this with $h(U + \Delta U) \approx h(U) + \langle \nabla h(U), \Delta U \rangle$,
we see that 
\begin{equation}
\nabla h(U) = 2 R^T(RU - H).
\end{equation}

Now setting the gradient of $f(U) = g(U) + h(U)$ equal to $0$, we obtain
\begin{align}
-(A - UW) W^T + R^T (RU - H) = 0
\end{align}
This is a [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) for $U$, and could be solved with standard techniques for Sylvester equations. 
For example, Matlab has a function called [sylvester](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sylvester.html).

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication by a fixed matrix is a linear operator on the vector space of matrices, and can be represented in matrix-vector form using [vectorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) and the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product):
$${\rm vec}(AXB) = (B^T\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(X),$$
where, if $X$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, then ${\rm vec}(X)$ is an $mn$-dimensional vector. For convenience, in the following I will denote ${\rm vec}(X)$ as $\bar X$. Of course, vectorization is linear: $\overline{X+Y} = \bar X+\bar Y$ and $\overline{aX}=a\bar X$ for scalar $a$. One can also readily verify that $\|X\|_F=\|\bar X\|$.

Then
$$\begin{align}
\|A-UW\|_F^2+\|RU-H\|_F^2 &= \|\overline{A-UW}\|^2+\|\overline{RU-H}\|^2 \\
&= \|\bar A-\overline{UW}\|^2+\|\overline{RU}-\bar H\|^2 \\
&= \|\bar A-(W^T\otimes I)\bar U\|^2+\|(I\otimes R)\bar U-\bar H\|^2 \\
\end{align}$$

which you can expand into a quadratic in $\bar U$ and minimize using linear algebra.

Comment: Thanks, Rahul and littleO! Both answers are useful, but I can only check one...

Comment: littleO's answer is better because it doesn't require you to build a massive $mn$-by-$mn$ matrix.